# how to embed a autoplay vimeo video on any page with "Click to play sound" overlay?

Tags: overlay, autoplay, vimeo-player

I want to add a Vimeo video with autoplay and an overlay saying "Click to play sound".

You can see the example here: https://trafficsecrets.com/thebook-5

In this video this is happening:

1. Vimeo video playing without sound with Play button overlay
2. When we click on the play button video starts from the beginning with the sound.
3. The above link is a click funnel example but I want to achieve this on an HTML page.